# Code snippets for methods in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, code-snippets

In Visual Studio I can type e.g.

> for <kbd>TAB</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd>

and a code snippet pops in.

Are there built-in code snippets for private, public, etc. methods as well?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

*ctor*: Default constructor

*prop*: Property

*propg*: Read-only property

*sim*: `static int main` method

*svm*: `static void main` method

There's a good list [here](http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/3557701/Introducing-Visual-Studio-2005-IntelliSense-Code-Snippets.htm). And if you want to make your own, the [Snippet Designer](https://github.com/mmanela/snippetdesigner) is very good.

[Here are all the Visual C# code snippets for Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-csharp-code-snippets)

Comment: You insert it with a shortcut keyword, like meth<Tab><Tab>, by going into the Properties pane and setting the Shortcut option (e.g., "meth")?

Comment: The link to the list gives a 404

Comment: @FelixMM Odd it redirected for me. Anyway I've updated it to the new location.

Comment: @CameronMacFarland it's awesome. please update it with 2017 link :)

Comment: Is there no built in snippet that allows you to do something like `sim` or `svm` and allow you to tab through it and modify it?

Comment: They can be discovered by Ctrl + K, Ctrl + X (at least with some versions of Visual Studio, including Visual Studio 2012). Perhaps include it in the answer?

Answer (score 42):

**You can download the method snippets as a [Visual Studio Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d4e9939d-baac-43d4-bece-960eb57e02c1?SRC=VSIDE).**

It supports the following:

```
method (typical method)

vmethod (virtual method)

smethod (static method)

xmethod (extension method)
```

1. In Visual Studio, go to menu *Tools* → *Extensions and Updates...*
2. Observe the *Extensions and Updates* window
3. Enter "C# Methods Code Snippets" in the search field (upper right)

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answers the question - code snippets for ***methods*** (from the question: *"...code snippets for private, public, etc.* ***methods*** *"*). The other answers are just generic answers about snippets.

Comment: I tried the search in Visual Studio 2012 (yes, I know) without finding the extension. I selected *"Online"* before entering *"C# Methods Code Snippets"*. I looked at the first 20 pages of 25 hits each (no end in sight). But I did find a number interesting items:  *"Import Code Snippet"*, *"CodeHelperTools"*, *"NUnit VS Templates"*, *"StyleCop"*, *"Language Convert"* (C# <-> VB.NET), *"Script#"* (transpile from C# to JavaScript),

Comment: cont' - *"Refactor"* (.NET assembly browser and decompiler), *"kiss!"* (template-based code generator for C#, VB.NET, and SQL), *"WPF MVVM project template"*, *"T4Awesome"*, *"SharpSetup"* (WiX, create installers), *"Units of Measurements"*, *".NET FTP library"*, and *"Comment"*.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to see the list of all available *snippets*:

- Press **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>** and then **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>**

Comment: Just to clarify, that's `CTRL` + `K` and then `CTRL` + `X`. For more info, see [How to: Use Code Snippets (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4c5cc9b(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: @Samir. Actually both works. However, updated to what Microsoft doc says.

Comment: That's right. It depends on how you formulate it. What was missing was "press and hold CTRL". But this works too.

Answer (score 13):

Below are the steps I used to create a custom snippet for Visual Studio 2010, but the steps work for Visual Studio 2008.

Create a new text file named *method.snippet* and paste the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>method</Title>
            <Shortcut>method</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for method</Description>
            <Author>Kevin Hogg</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>methodname</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Method name</ToolTip>
                    <Function>MethodName()</Function>
                    <Default>MethodNamePlaceholder</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[public void $methodname$ ()
    {
        $end$
    }]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Copy your file into the snippets folder in Windows Explorer:

- Visual Studio 2010: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
  10.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#
- Visual Studio 2008: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#

Once you save your file, the snippets are automatically loaded, so you can now open Visual Studio and type:

```
method<tab><tab>
```

*where <tab> is the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key on your keyboard.

You should now see the following created, with the MethodNamePlaceholder highlighted so you can change the name.

```
public void MethodNamePlaceholder()
{

}
```

Comment: Please note I could only test this in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: It also works on VS2013
Path :
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#

Comment: Works VS2015. Thanks. Great DYI. Check the box for learned something new today.

Comment: VS2019: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC#\Snippets\1031\Visual C#`

Answer (score 9):

Some of the snippets I use, also mentioned at MSDN, follows:

> 1. '**#if**        Creates a #if directive and a #endif directive.
> 2. '**#region**    Creates a #region directive and a #endregion directive.
> 3. **~**           Creates a destructor for the containing class.
> 4. **attribute**   Creates a declaration for a class that derives from Attribute.
> 5. **checked**     Creates a checked block.
> 6. **class**       Creates a class declaration.
> 7. **ctor**        Creates a constructor for the containing class.
> 8. **cw**          Creates a call to WriteLine.
> 9. **do**          Creates a do while loop.
> 10. **else**       Creates an else block.
> 11. **enum**       Creates an enum declaration.
> 12. **equals**     Creates a method declaration that overrides the Equals method defined in the Object class.
> 13. **exception**  Creates a declaration for a class that derives from an exception (Exception by default).
> 14. **for**        Creates a for loop.
> 15. **foreach**    Creates a foreach loop.
> 16. **forr**       Creates a for loop that decrements the loop variable after each iteration.
> 17. **if**         Creates an if block.
> 18. **indexer**    Creates an indexer declaration.
> 19. **interface**  Creates an interface declaration.
> 20. **invoke**     Creates a block that safely invokes an event.
> 21. **iterator**   Creates an iterator.
> 22. **iterindex**  Creates a "named" iterator and indexer pair by using a nested class.
> 23. **lock**       Creates a lock block.
> 24. **mbox**       Creates a call to MessageBox.Show. You may have to add a reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll.
> 25. **namespace**  Creates a namespace declaration.
> 26. **prop**       Creates an auto-implemented property declaration.
> 27. **propfull**   Creates a property declaration with get and set accessors.
> 28. **propg**      Creates a read-only auto-implemented property with a private "set" accessor.
> 29. **sim**        Creates a static int Main method declaration.
> 30. **struct**     Creates a struct declaration.
> 31. **svm**        Creates a static void Main method declaration.
> 32. **switch**     Creates a switch block.
> 33. **try**        Creates a try-catch block.
> 34. **tryf**       Creates a try-finally block.
> 35. **unchecked**  Creates an unchecked block.
> 36. **unsafe**     Creates an unsafe block.
> 37. **using**      Creates a using directive.
> 38. **while**      Creates a while loop.

Comment: They can be discovered by Ctrl + K, Ctrl + X (at least with some versions of Visual Studio, including Visual Studio 2012). Perhaps include it in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I made my own snippet for a method. The XML code for it is the following, and you can add it to a file called "my_method.snippet" (or whatever_you_want.snippet) in C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets (your path might be different because I use VS2012):

```
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
        <Title>method</Title>
        <Shortcut>method</Shortcut>
        <SnippetTypes>
            <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
        </SnippetTypes>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
        <Declarations>
            <Literal>
                <ID>access_modifier</ID>
                <Default>private</Default>
            </Literal>
            <Literal>
                <ID>return_type</ID>
                <Default>void</Default>
            </Literal>
            <Literal>
                <ID>name</ID>
                <Default>New_method</Default>
            </Literal>
        </Declarations>
        <Code Language="csharp">
            <![CDATA[$access_modifier$ $return_type$ $name$ ()
    {
    $end$
    }]]>
        </Code>
    </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create customs snippets.
Like this:

http://www.mediafire.com/file/gz3tzjnydk5/meth.snippet

Comment: That link is for a page about the meth.snippet XML document format (.SNIPP). That is far away from being about custom snippets. I suggest adding an example and/or more information to make this answer more useful.

Answer (score -2):

The code snippet for properties is:

> prop<kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>