# Is there a shortcut in VisualStudio to create a method?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, shortcut

Is there a shortcut in VisualStudio to create a method, like there is "prop, tab" for a property and "ctor, tab" for a constructor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio code snippet for method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292164/visual-studio-code-snippet-for-method)

Comment: You are welcome. But Habib's answer is also useful.

Comment: Try resharper. It does everything good in VS.

Comment: ) In my opinion Habib's answer is more appropriate. I was late about some seconds to post the same answer. ))

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev yeah...it might be. I just don't know what VS can do since 2008, since I always run Resharper.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no [Code snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-csharp-code-snippets) to create a method other than `Main`, but you can do the following.

Type your *to be* method name, pass the parameters, once done you will notice a red underline at the beginning of method name. Click that (or click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>), it will give you the option to create method like this:

[image: Screenshot of implementation]

This will generate a method like the following:

```cs
private static void MySomeMethod(int a, string b)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 14):

There is another clever way for create method (extract).

This way I use if I have method and I would like part of this method move to new private method.

1. Select part of code in method which you would like to extract.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>  or right click on selected code → Refactor\Extract\Extract Method...

This will create only new private method but automatically set input parameters and output parameter.

Answer (score 10):

1. Save the following Code snippet into a file with '.snippet' extension

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
>     <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
>         <Header>
>             <Title>Generate Method Stub</Title>
>           <Description>Create a new method</Description>
>           <Author>Anoop Simon</Author>
>          <Shortcut>stub</Shortcut>
>         </Header>
>         <Snippet>
>            <Code Language="CSharp">
>           <![CDATA[public string DummyMethod(string arg1,string arg2)
>           {
>               return string.Empty;
>           }
>           ]]>
>       </Code>
>         </Snippet>
>     </CodeSnippet>
> </CodeSnippets>
> ```

2. Open Visual Studio .
3. Got to Tools --> Code Snippets Manager.. (Ctrl +K , Ctrl + B)
   [image]
4. Import the file saved earlier
5. Click OK
6. Open Any C# class in Visual Studio IDE
7. type 'stub' then press TAB key twice . If you wish to change the shortcut, update value of  tag in the snippet file

Answer (score 8):

check [`Code Snippets`](http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/3557701/Introducing-Visual-Studio-2005-IntelliSense-Code-Snippets.htm)

sim: static int main method

svm: static void main method

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guidelines to create [custom code snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2022).

You can make your own code snippet, or just use this template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>create new 'not implemented' method</Title>
      <Description>create new 'not implemented' method</Description>
      <Shortcut>emptymethod</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="CSharp">
        <![CDATA[        $access specifier$ $return type$ $methodName$($params$)
        {
            $throw new NotImplementedException()$;
        }]]>
      </Code>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal>
          <ID>access specifier</ID>
          <Default>Array</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>return type</ID>
          <Default>returnType</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>methodName</ID>
          <Default>methodName</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>params</ID>
          <Default>params</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>throw new NotImplementedException()</ID>
          <Default>throw new NotImplementedException()</Default>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

after you import this snippet to your visual studio,
when you press `emptymethod` + `tab` , you will get new not implemented method.

Answer (score -3):

Type 'fun' then tab.
Ta-da!
And now I need to type more characters because the minimum allowed number of characters is 30.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).