# Is there a shortcut in Netbeans to create a method?

Tags: php, netbeans

Is there a shortcut in the Apache Netbeans IDE (e.g. for PHP) to create a method (with inputs etc.) like in Visual Studio, as shown in the following answer:

[Is there a shortcut in Visual Studio to create a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23811520/9620269)

---

### Visual Studio example

**IDE hint:**

[image]

**The VS shortcut generates a method like this:**

```cs
    private static void MySomeMethod(int a, string b)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

---

Sorry, I copied the infos from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23811520/9620269) to explain my question, because I don't have Visual Studio on my current PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no code snippet or such shortcuts for generating a method stub available in Apache NetBeans IDE yet. Rather, there are many advantages available in it which aren't in Visual Studio and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

ALT + Enter works for me (tested on Linux)

[ALT+Enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Wn7r.png)

[generated code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5emrn.png)