# Is there a code snippet in Visual Studio community IDE?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, code-snippets

Is there a way to generate custom code in Visual Studio COMMUNITY IDE (NOT Visual Studio CODE).

Can you create custom code snippets in Visual Studio IDE?

For example, I type `main` and it generates

```
//
int main() {

return 0;

}
//
```

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2019

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code snippets for methods in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292164/code-snippets-for-methods-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Thank you so much both to Sergey Vlasov and Hoppeduppeanut! I appreciate it.